# Python 3 annotation - method returning instance of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I started using annotations recently. I have a singleton instance, hence I have a `get_instance` method whose return value has the same type of the class the method belongs to.

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_instance(self) -> Singleton:  # Obviously the interpreter complains about undefined name
        pass
```

What is the correct way to annotate the `get_instance` method?